# Node.js using import is not working without the --experimental-modules flag

Tags: node.js

According to Node's documentation (https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html), you can use the .js extension and ES modules if you add "type": "module" to package.json

I'm doing a simple test, my package.json:

```
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

server.js:

```
import * as http from 'http';

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Server is OK');
});

server.listen(8000, '127.0.0.1', () => {
  console.log('Server listening...');
});
```

`node -v` is `v12.16.1`

Running `node server.js` with this setup should work. But I must explicitly use `--experimental-modules` flag... otherwise I get: `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:...`
What am I missing?

Comment: You're using node 12, the documentation you read is for node 13.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes sorry, just updated the link. The referred section still holds the same instructions, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES modules without `--experimental-modules` flag only [since node `12.17.0`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V12.md#2020-05-26-version-12170-erbium-lts-targos) (it was backported from 14.x branch)

In earlier versions you must use the flag.